# Mountain range identification algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, geography

If I have a photo that shows a mountain range, is there an algorithm or methodology to try to search and find that mountain range? For example, let's say I have an old photo like this one (fragment):

[image: mountain ranges]

So here we can see 3 distinct mountain ranges in the background, and by hand we could outline their profile against the sky or against the range behind it.

Given these profile lines as input is there an algorithm that will match this to a DEM? The overall goal would be to find out where the photo was taken.

Comment: Note that the shape of the skyline depends on the visibility; e.g. there may be several more mountains behind the visible ones, but hidden by cloud/haze. This makes an already difficult problem even harder...

Comment: @DNA This is irrelevant to my question. Assume you have an accurate profile of the mountain range or ranges in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such algorithms do exist, at least for constrained areas. See for example the paper:

**User-Driven Geolocation of Untagged Desert Imagery Using Digital Elevation Models**, Tzeng, E. et al, Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops (CVPRW), 23-28 June 2013, Portland OR.

> ([Abstract](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6595881)): We propose a system for user-aided visual
> localization of desert imagery without the use of any metadata such as
> GPS readings, camera focal length, or field-of-view. The system makes
> use only of publicly available digital elevation models (DEMs) to
> rapidly and accurately locate photographs in non-urban environments
> such as deserts. Our system generates synthetic skyline views from a
> DEM and extracts stable concavity-based features from these skylines
> to form a database. To localize queries, a user manually traces the
> skyline on an input photograph. The skyline is automatically refined
> based on this estimate, and the same concavity-based features are
> extracted. We then apply a variety of geometrically constrained
> matching techniques to efficiently and accurately match the query
> skyline to a database skyline, thereby localizing the query image. We
> evaluate our system using a test set of 44 ground-truthed images over
> a 10, 000 km2 region of interest in a desert and show that in many
> cases, queries can be localized with precision as fine as 100 m2.

The full paper is also [available](http://www-video.eecs.berkeley.edu/papers/ezheng/paper.pdf).

How far this technique scales (e.g. worldwide) is a different matter of course...

Another [relevant paper](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/pomarc/pubs/BaatzECCV12.pdf) is:

**Large Scale Visual Geo-Localization of Images in Mountainous Terrain**, Georges Baatz et al, Proc. European Conference on Computer Vision, 2012

> Abstract. Given a picture taken somewhere in the world, automatic
> geo-localization of that image is a task that would be extremely
> useful e.g. for historical and forensic sciences, documentation purposes, organization of the world’s photo material and also intelligence
> applications. While tremendous progress has been made over the last
> years in visual location recognition within a single city,
> localization in natural environments is much more difficult, since
> vegetation, illumination, seasonal changes make appearance-only
> approaches impractical. In this work, we target mountainous terrain
> and use digital elevation models to extract representations for fast
> visual database lookup. We propose an automated approach for very
> large scale visual localization that can efficiently exploit visual
> information (contours) and geometric constraints (consistent
> orientation) at the same time. We validate the system on the scale of
> a whole country (Switzerland, 40000km 2 ) using a new dataset of more
> than 200 landscape query pictures with ground truth.

Comment: That is very interesting. That is EXACTLY the kind of algorithm I am looking for. Unfortunately, no exact details on the algorithm are provided. Do I need to contact the authors to get the details of the algorithm?

Comment: I've added a link to the [full paper](http://www-video.eecs.berkeley.edu/papers/ezheng/paper.pdf), hope that helps - for any additional detail, I think you'd need to talk to the authors.